# How do I resolve this curl-related error?

Tags: python, pycurl

please tell me the solution

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pycurl.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pycurl.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Downvoted for complete lack of detail in question. Posting an error message with only "please tell me the solution"... very poor.

Comment: Add the source from the code you're using, we can't help you otherwise! (Reading the faq {http://stackoverflow.com/faq} would help too)

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to invoke the cURL library, but you don't have curl installed (or it's not installed properly). It looks like you're running Linux, so simply install the appropriate package (for instance, `sudo apt-get install curl` if you're on Ubuntu).